# How to use a reverse url lookup with argument in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have the following URL config in my `Django` project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.record_create),
    path('<entry_method>/', views.record_create, name = "record_create"),
]
```

The view goes:

```
def record_create(request, entry_method="bulk/"):
```

In my template I do:

```
<a href="{% url "record_create" entry_method=request.path_info %}">
```

And I get the following error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'record_create' with keyword arguments '{'entry_method': '/bulk/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<entry_method>[^/]+)/$']
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the reverse lookup. The problem is that your `entry_method` in the url patterns, is by default a `str` path converter, not a `path`. You can set the type of the parameter with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.record_create),
    path('<path:entry_method>', views.record_create, name = "record_create"),
]
```

For more information, see the documentation on [*Path converters* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters).